# Encrypt sentence with sentence's keyword in PHP

Tags: php

I want to encrypt a sentence using its keyword. For example the sentence "I LOVE YOU" with keyword "LOVE" will become "T ZJZP MJY".

```
Words = I LOVE YOU
Keyword = LOVE
Encrypt = T ZJZP MJY
```

Letter "A" will start at letter "L" since "L" is the start of the keyword and it will stop in letter "I" of the words which directs to letter "T". And then letter "A" will start at letter "O" of the keyword so that "L" of the words will be "Z". An then letter "A" will start at "V" of the keyword to get "J".

Keyword should be in the sentence.

Tried this one, but stuck.

```
$word = "I LOVE YOU";
$keyword = "LOVE";
$letters = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

$keyword = str_split($keyword);
$word = str_split($word);
$newWord = "";

for($x=0; $x<26 ; $x++){
    for($y=0; $y<sizeof($keyword); $y++){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure StackOverflow is the correct exchange to be posting this on but I'll answer it anyway, what you're looking for is an [OTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) method, more specifically a rolling OTP method (meaning it repeats the key/pad to account for the full length of the input.

The most common OTP method is to XOR, I'll show you the code first and explain it after

```
function OTP($input, $pad) {
    $inputlen = strlen($input);
    $padlen = strlen($pad);
    $inputbytes = unpack("C*", $input); //Unpack C* will convert a string into a byte array, such as 'abc' to Array(0x61, 0x62, 0x63)
    $padbytes = unpack("C*", $pad);

    $output = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $inputlen; $i++) //Loop through the input string
        $output .= chr($inputbytes[$i + 1] ^ $padbytes[$i % $padlen + 1]);
    return $output;
}
```

After getting byte arrays of each string using `unpack` with the `C*` option you'd loop through the input string, XORing it `^` by the pad character at the same position (mod `%` the length). `$i % $padlength` makes sure that the for loop will never loop to an index that's larger than the length of the string, for example if you had a string 'ABC' which has a length of 3 and the `for` loop looped to 3 it would throw an index out of bounds error, however if you had `$i % <the length of the string>` when the `for` loop looped to 3 the calculation would equal 0, because `3 % 3 = 0`, and `4 % 3 = 1`.

When using unpack you absolutely must add 1 to the index, as the byte array is *not* zero-indexed.

[Here is an example of its use](http://3v4l.org/DHniG)

*Fun fact:* This encryption when used correctly is completely unbreakable